# Inconveniente con la Conexión Excel con base de datos Mysql en la nube

Tags: mysql, excel, phpmyadmin, vba

Cordial saludo
solicito su colaboración por favor, con el siguiente inconveniente:

Cree dentro de 000webhost una base de datos, que tiene las siguientes características:
Nombre de la Base de Datos: id19610817_xxxxx
Usuario de la Base de Datos: id19610817_root
Host de la Base de datos: localhost

Y en el Connector/ODBC, tengo lo siguiente:
Data Source Name: Conex_excelwithMysql
TCP/IP Server: localhost
Port: 3306
User: id19610817_root

Al momento de probar la conexión con el Test, me muestra el siguiente error:
Connection Failed [Mysql][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver]Access denied for user ‘id19610817_root’@’localhost’ (using password: NO)

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Intenta darle al usuario el host `%`, y en el ODBC el servidor debería ser el host de 000webhost, ya sea la IP o un dominio que resuelva a dicha IP.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias realice en el ODBC lo que me comentaba pero desafortunadamente el error que me muestra es el siguiente:  Connection failed with the following error:   [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver] Unknown MySQL server host '000webhost'(1101)[HY000]

Comment: En 000webhost hay muchas bases de datos, de varios sitios de varios usuarios ¿Cómo le dirías al ODBC cuál -o en dónde- está la tuya?. Por cierto, con el servicio gratuito no puedes hacer conexiones remotas.